# ArcGIS Model isn't accepting my SQL Query

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, sql

I'm running a model that breaks a dataset into several dbf tables based on a query. However, only half of the query is being honored.[image][image]

The PopDenZone field is not being accepted and I am getting other values in the output, but not all of the total, maybe 50-100 records are being thrown into the output from other Density Zones.

Anybody know what could be causing this behavior? The portion of the query where I need specific Priority Descriptions is working correctly.

Using ArcGIS 10.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need parentheses around part of the expression? Either of the following could be correct, but I assume it is the latter.

```
(PopDenZone = 'CPSE URBAN' AND Priority_Description = 'Life Threat') OR Priority_Description = 'Urgent Medical' 

PopDenZone = 'CPSE URBAN' AND (Priority_Description = 'Life Threat' OR Priority_Description = 'Urgent Medical')
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps try parentheses around the expressions. I think what you're trying to say is:

```
PopDenZone = 'CPSE URBAN' AND (Priority_Description = 'Life Threat' OR Priority_Description = 'Urgent Medical')
```

It's worth noting that:

```
(x AND y) OR z
```

is different to:

```
x AND (y OR z)
```